# Can one add reasonable assumptions that we have $depth\ R \geq depth\ M$ for every $R$-module $M$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

Let $(R,m)$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring which  is not CM. Let $M$ be a finite $R$-module.
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090630/what-inequalities-can-one-have-between-depth-r-and-depth-m-when-depth-r), Hanno shows that one can  have any inequality  between $depth\ R$ and $depth\ M.$ Still, the 2nd part of question has not answer. After a year I edit the question and ask 2nd part as a separate question:

> Can one add reasonable assumptions that we have  $depth\ R \geq  depth\ M$ for *every* $R$-module $M$?

Comment: When you say `add reasonable assumption', what exactly do you mean? Are you asking whether it is always true? In which case the answer is no.

Comment: i mean non-trivial assumptions added (on ring for example) so that we have  $depth\ R \geq  depth\ M$ for every $R$-moule $M$

Comment: There are many classes (quite general) of non CM rings as above which have finitely generated maximal CM modules. So, I am not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: I want assumptions that we have $depth\ R \geq  depth\ M$ for **_Every_** $R$-module $M$, not *some* modules

Comment: For all reasonable rings, this can not happen is a conjecture of Hochster (though last time I talked to him, he was not so sure he believes it now). The conjecture is, such rings have a finite module which is maximal Cohen-Macaulay. So, if $R$ is not CM, such inequalities can not occur. In particular, if such examples exist, it may not be easy to find.

Comment: thank you. can you post this as an answer to exclude this from ananswered list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer as you said.

For all reasonable rings, this can not happen is a conjecture of Hochster (though last time I talked to him, he was not so sure he believes it now). The conjecture is, such rings have a finite module which is maximal Cohen-Macaulay. So, if $R$ is not CM, such inequalities can not occur. In particular, if such examples exist, it may not be easy to find.